# Issue exporting GeoPandas dataframe

Tags: python, export, shapely, geopandas

I am trying to export a GeoPandas Dataframe looking like this to an external file:

```
id   geometry
0    POLYGON ((39.92713 1.41394, 39.92703 1.41394, ...
1    POLYGON ((39.95126 1.41866, 39.95116 1.41867, ...
2    POLYGON ((39.94181 1.42505, 39.94171 1.42506, ...
3    POLYGON ((39.95875 1.43338, 39.95866 1.43339, ...
4    POLYGON ((39.96375 1.44061, 39.96366 1.44061, ...
..                                                 ...
105  POLYGON ((39.89128 1.57005, 39.89118 1.57005, ...
106  POLYGON ((39.84598 1.56894, 39.84588 1.56894, ...
107  POLYGON ((39.74900 1.56838, 39.74891 1.56839, ...
108  POLYGON ((39.78401 1.57033, 39.78392 1.57034, ...
109  POLYGON ((39.85403 1.56422, 39.85393 1.56422, ...
```

In fact, when I run the following, I get a file with empty geometry.

```
gdf.to_file('file.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Any tentative solution?

Comment: How did you install geopandas? This should normally work, there will likely be an issue on your machine.

Comment: Does your geodataframe have the `geometry` column set as the "geometry" column? `gdf.area` should return non-zeros. Or, is your CRS set? `gdf.crs` should be non-None.